# Plot dimension m of n ValueDimensions in TemporalData: with proper temporal values

Tags: plotting, time-series

I have a `TemporalData` object that has `td["ValueDimensions"] =3`.
Right now I only have one sample, `K=1`. So the following example is the simplest case, `dim=3` and `K=1`.
To begin with, I just want to plot each dimension separately.  Should be trivial but it seems I have to twist the `td` object into knots to get the time dimension to show correctly...

```
 ts = {{{0.`, {1.333999006891247`, 12.053810602014542`, 
 87.94618939798545`}}, {0.1`, {1.3514434090695817`, 
 12.093415930914793`, 
 86.53455823856495`}}, {0.2`, {1.2484079436257138`, 
 12.25553483931355`, 
 92.89743502043808`}}, {0.30000000000000004`, \
 {1.3781565261854645`, 12.184908506564101`, 
 84.45147211241067`}}, {0.4`, {1.3285491537059095`, 
 12.29338463899116`, 
 87.1154457958651`}}, {0.5`, {1.353124500190124`, 
 12.328305046121512`, 
 85.38069968635773`}}, {0.6000000000000001`, {1.4134624696453986`,
  12.326915095624361`, 
 81.70867228313669`}}, {0.7000000000000001`, {1.195964818586219`, 
 12.60441567097316`, 
 94.68144692187659`}}, {0.8`, {1.2736346893937893`, 
 12.587741552453553`, 
 89.29573476671187`}}, {0.9`, {1.0705151506735828`, 
 12.853307642920917`, 
 103.2366857670525`}}, {1.`, {0.9802798326333646`, 
 13.00862708606569`, 110.54583685327417`}}}}
tds = TemporalData[ts]
ListLinePlot[td]
(* Pols suggests if "ValuesDimension" returns 3 then this would just work *)
ListLinePlot[td["Values", 1]]
ListLinePlot[td["Values", 2]]
ListLinePlot[td["Values", 3]]

(* The following shows on dimension for the one path, but feels wrong on so many levels, e.g. the time dimension has been lost*)
tds["ValueList"][[1, All, 1]] // ListLinePlot
```

Once I can do this, I'd like to generate (using ItoProcess) K paths instead of just one, and then I'd like to plot each of these.

Would appreciate any hints or tips about how to do this elegantly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is undocumented:

```
tds["PathComponents"]
```

[image]

```
ListLinePlot @ tds["PathComponents"]
```

[image]

Plot component 3 only

```
ListLinePlot @ tds["PathComponent", 3]  
(* or *) ListLinePlot @ tds["PathComponents"][[3]]
```

[image]

The property `"PathComponent"` and the form `tds["PathComponent", componentnumber]` are undocumented.

Both `"PathComponents"` nor `PathComponent"` work in versions 9.0, 11.3 and  12.0 although neither appear in the property list:

```
tds["Properties"]
```

> {Components, DateList, DatePath, DatePaths, Dates, FirstDates, FirstTimes, FirstValues, LastDates, LastTimes, LastValues, Part,Path, PathCount, PathFunction, PathFunctions, PathLength, PathLengths, Paths, PathTimes, SliceData, SliceDistribution, TimeList, Times, ValueDimensions, ValueList, Values}

Comment: Many thanks.  Could you add "The following is undocumented:" as the first line.   This will forewarn others in case wolfram change this behavior to some thing else undocumented.  Then I'll accept the answer.  I'm the OP and I was annoyed with myself . Its reasonable others think "The lazy so-and-so.  Why didn't he just read the docs about this". Any insight into how to elegantly select dimension M of sample/Simulation K.

Comment: @Hedgehog, done.