# Stochastic Lotka-Volterra Predator-Prey Model

Tags: stochastic-calculus, ecology

I am struggling with writing a stochastic version of Lotka-Volterra predator-prey model.
This is as far as I have gotten:

```
a = 0.1;
b = 0.2;
c = 0.3;
d = 0.4;
proc = 
  RandomFunction[
    ItoProcess[
      {\[DifferentialD]X[t] == (a \[DifferentialD]t X[t] + \[DifferentialD]W[t]) - 
         b \[DifferentialD]t X[t] Y[t],
       \[DifferentialD]Y[t] == -c \[DifferentialD]t Y[t] + 
       d \[DifferentialD]t Y[t] X[t]}, 
      {X[t], Y[t]}, {{X, Y}, {0.2, 0.2}}, t, 
      W \[Distributed] WienerProcess[0, 0.1]], {0, 100, 0.01}, 
      Method -> "StochasticRungeKuttaScalarNoise"];
ListLinePlot[proc, PlotRange -> All]
```

For some reason, only one variable depends on the stochastic noise and it does not bear influence on the other part of the equation, I have tried to correct it, but no matter what I do, no luck.

First thing would be to get it working correctly, then I would worry about excluding "extinction Values > 0", since we are not interested in those.

Also, in regards to the graph, is there other way I would create a phase plot (X against Y)? My current way:

```
ListLinePlot[proc["Values"], PlotRange -> All]
```

plots `X` and `Y`, against time. How would I plot only X in time?

Comment: As to the 2nd question, you might try `ListLinePlot[Transpose@proc["Values"], PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: Oh right, that plots amplitude of both functions (x and y) in time, on the same graph. Would there be a way to separate those functions,  and create two graphs, first with only function X values in time, and second with only function Y values in time? @m_goldberg

Answer (score 2):

There are a few questions wrapped up here.  Let me try to take them one-by-one.

> only one variable depends on the stochastic noise and it does not bear influence on the other part of the equation

I don't think that's actually correct.  After running your code,

```
ListLinePlot[proc, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The predator (gold) seems to smooth over the variation in the prey (blue) but take a look around `t=85`: there is a random bump in prey which results in a little shoulder in the decline of the predators.  So I think the simulation results are accurate for this model and parameter set.

> then I would worry about excluding "extinction Values > 0", since we are not interested in those.

That prey can become negative is a problem with the model formulation.  I don't think `RandomFunction[ItoProcess` has the equivalent of `WhenEvent` in `NDSolve`.

Two ideas: 1) replace your additive noise `\[DifferentialD]W[t]` with a multiplicative noise `X[t] \[DifferentialD]W[t]`, which seems like it should prevent the prey population from becoming negative.  2) Instead of using a stochastic differential equation as your model, you could use a more basic continuous time stochastic process and simulate it with @IstvánZachar's `GillespieSSA` function from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119786/gillespie-stochastic-simulation-algorithm/119788#119788) (specifically, see his example 2).

> is there other way I would create a phase plot (X against Y)?

Funny, when I run your code, it works as desired (v11.2):

```
ListLinePlot[proc["Values"], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> How would I plot only X in time?

[This recent answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/162844/6358) by @kglr addresses this point, using an undocumented property `"PathComponent"`:

```
ListLinePlot[proc["PathComponent", 1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Anyone want to write a wrapper (call it `SNDSolve`) for `RandomFunction[ItoProcess` that mimics `NDSolve` in input and output?  Seems like it'd be appreciated by many!

Comment: Or maybe `NSDSolve` makes more sense ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation.
 
In regards to the phase graph, I was just wondering whether mine was a correct way of doing it, since I was not able to find "Values" or "PathComponent" anywhere online...

I will try to tweak it for the extinction event case. 

Once again, thank you!

Comment: If this answers your question, you can accept it by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 1):

This solution will first define the `ItoProcess` and *then* simulate it; care is taken to initialize all the available parameters at their appropriate values (using `With`):

```
With[{a = 0.1, b = 0.2, c = 0.3, d = 0.4, Xo = 0.2, Yo = 0.2, wm = 0.,ws = 0.1},
 proc = ItoProcess[{
    \[DifferentialD]X[t] == (a - b Y[t]) X[t] \[DifferentialD]t + \[DifferentialD]W[t],
    \[DifferentialD]Y[t] == (-c + d X[t]) Y[t] \[DifferentialD]t
   }, {X[t], Y[t]}, {{X, Y}, {Xo, Yo}},
   t, W \[Distributed] WienerProcess[wm, ws]
  ]
 ];
```

Next, we simulate 3 *paths* for the process (`proc`):

```
td = RandomFunction[proc, {0, 100, 0.01}, 3, Method -> "StochasticRungeKuttaScalarNoise"]
```

Finally we plot the derived paths:

```
Grid[
 Partition[
  MapIndexed[

   With[{val = Part[#1, All, -1]},
     ListLinePlot[
      Transpose[val],
      PlotRange -> All,
      PlotLegends -> {X[t], Y[t]},
      PlotLabel -> Row[{Path, Null, #2[[-1]]}]
    ]] &, td["Paths"]], 2, 2, {1, 1}, Null]]
```

[image]